# Expressing Matrix in term its orthogonal

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given $m<n$. Suppose that $H$ and $K$ be $m \times n$ and $n\times (n-m)$ matrices such that rank$(H)=m$, rank$(K)=n-m$, and $HK=0$. For fixed non singular symmetric matrix $A$ define
\begin{equation}
\ P=(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TA.
\end{equation}

I'd like to express $P$ in term of $H$ and $A$ without involving $K$. I am sure we can do this because I could prove $KP=I-A^{-1}H^T(HA^{-1}H^T)^{-1}H$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. However, what I want is expressing $P$.

Can anyone help me? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\widetilde{K} = 2K$. We have:

- $\operatorname{rank} \widetilde{K} = \operatorname{rank} K = n - m$,
- $H \widetilde{K} = 2 H K = 0$.

So, $\widetilde{K}$ satisfies the same conditions as $K$. Now, define

$$\widetilde{P} := (\widetilde{K}^T A \widetilde{K})^{-1} \widetilde{K}^T A.$$

It is easy to see that

$$\widetilde{P} = (\widetilde{K}^T A \widetilde{K})^{-1} \widetilde{K}^T A = ((2K)^T A (2K))^{-1} (2K)^T A = \frac{1}{2} (K^T A K)^{-1} K^T A = \frac{1}{2}P.$$

But the only thing we changed was $K$ (while satisfying the given conditions), so $P$ must depend on $K$, and you cannot get a formula depending only on $H$ and $A$ (neither of which we've changed), except when $P = 0$.